# Do I have the right lens hood for my Canon 1000D with EF-S 18-55mm kit lens?

Tags: canon, kit-lens, lens-hood

I'm starting into the realm of photography and learning about the various additions to cameras that assist in good photos.

I have the Canon EOS 1000d, I believe the Rebel in the US? It came with the stock lens EF-S 18-55mm. (Unfortunately at the time, I wasn't aware of "Image Stabilizer" so it's not an IS lens.)

So my question: I bought a petal lens hood from Amazon.co.uk as I couldn't find mention of a Canon one anywhere. [Product is here](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B004HZ1XM8/ref=oss_product).

Maybe I have the wrong one? When I attach it as tight as it will screw on, it rotates when focusing, so then I see the sides of the hood in photos. When it is perpendicular it seems fine and no shadowing.

I loosened it and can move it into position when focusing but it just seems to much hassle.

Maybe I'm using the clamp ring wrong.

What do you all think? At 6.99 pounds it isn't a complete loss if it is wrong.

Comment: See also [Why are some lens hoods petal shaped and others not?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/399/why-are-some-lens-hoods-petal-shaped-and-others-not)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Canon EF-S 18-55mm lens has a rotating end, which is used for focusing (i'm sure you're aware of this). So a petal-based hood is definitely the wrong choice for this lens. That Amazon seller is marketing it wrongly, IMO.

You'll find that higher-end lenses have a fixed (rotationally speaking) end, and so can be used with a petal hood.

My advice would be to either find a non-petal hood, or to not use one at all.

Answer (score 8):

That particular lens has a rotating front element which is undesirable for a number of reasons, one being that you can't attach a hood without it rotating (the other main reason being certain filters are orientation sensitive, such as a polarizer, graduated neutral density and these will also rotate when focussing).

There is an official non petal shaped hood available for the 18-55, the Canon EW-60C, but it's much smaller due to the need to accommodate the 18mm wide angle of view:

[image]

photo by [MJ/TR (´･ω･)](http://www.flickr.com/photos/mujitra)

Comment: Thanks, I could not find it anywhere. Although, I think I won't bother with it and maybe just save up and get a different lens altogether with IS. Is there any way I can tell from the spec sheets if the front rotates or not?

Comment: It's not commonly specified, but only the cheapest lenses have rotating filter mounts.

Comment: It will normally be mentioned in lens reviews if the filter mount rotates or not.

Answer (score 2):

in fact if the lens front element rotates when focusing, then the petal lens hood is not good idea. I have a cheap Tamron 70-300 telezoom lens and it is shipped with standard "tube" hood.

Second, the one you found looks like the one with screw-thread. I think that Canon also uses bayonet mount for hoods like my Pentax. So as I needed hood for my 18-55 mm lens, I first looked on Pentax  website and found that the original hood is called "*PH-RBA*". Then I searched ebay and found some replacement hood for much smaller price, which had in description "*Lens Hood for PENTAX SMC DA 18-55mm F3.5-5.6 AL II Lens replaces PH-RBA 52mm*" and it had the same bayonet mount as the original lens hood.