# Should I use a petal or round lens hood on a Canon 18-55 lens?

Tags: canon, lens-hood

I'm planning to get my 18-55 Canon kit lens a lens hood to protect it from the elements. Which would be the correct hood: a petal hood or a round one?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I have the right lens hood for my Canon 1000D with EF-S 18-55mm kit lens?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12600/do-i-have-the-right-lens-hood-for-my-canon-1000d-with-ef-s-18-55mm-kit-lens)

Comment: Also see [Why are some lens hoods petal shaped and others not?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/399/why-are-some-lens-hoods-petal-shaped-and-others-not)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I have the right lens hood for my Canon 1000D with EF-S 18-55mm kit lens?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/12600/do-i-have-the-right-lens-hood-for-my-canon-1000d-with-ef-s-18-55mm-kit-lens)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need a round one because the front element will rotate when it zooms/focuses.

Answer (score 2):

The [EW-60C](http://shop.usa.canon.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/product_10051_10051_171933_-1) seems to be what Canon specs for this lens. That's a round one. Note that a lens hood is designed more to protect from stray light bouncing around inside the lens barrel and/or reducing flare than it is for physical protection from the elements. If you are just trying to provide a bit more protection, be sure to put a skylight or UV filter on the lens.